# Advantages and disadvantages of having more move selectors in the union in local search

Tags: optaplanner

I want an opinion when it comes to the number of move selectors in local search. Does adding a new move selector (with a given move type) is more positive than negative in most of the use cases. Meaning does it help the algorithms to more quickly escape from local optima , or does it distract the algorithm more with having the additional move types?

And also is there a way to have control of which move types will be played out more than others ,based on the current state of the solution and the constraint violations that are present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's usually better if you're running for longer than a few seconds, as it gives more diversity. The default config only has change and swap moves, so one can argue it needs pillar change, pillar swap, 2opt, ... but that depends on the use case. Knapsack needs the pillar swap for example and vehicle routing needs the 2opt, but vica versa they're useless. I do expect that a future version will recognize the chained var and therefore the default config will include 2opts.

As for controlling the move types: you statically make one move type be selected twice as much as another. Or with the probablistic selector you can even differ it per move instance (although you'll need to be able to cache all moves, so not for big datasets).

But out-of-the-box there's not for dynamically changing the move type based on the state of the solution. This is **hyper-heuristics** really: if the the best score is unimproved for 100 steps, switch to the second moveSelector, etc. Although it's probably possible to do something similar with multiple solver phases and the unimproved step termination, it will be better once we have out of the box support for hyper-heuristics.

Also note that based on the constraint matches - and soon the indictment map (which is the reverse map of the constraint match total map), we 'll look into **Guided Local Search**, by selected entities with a higher indictment count (= involved in more constraint breaches) more often than the other entities.

Comment: Are hyper-heuristics and Guided Local Search planned for future versions of OptaPlanner?